# Do not allow two pods of the same application on same node in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We have a situation now when 2 pods of same type can run on the same node. Sometimes during restarts and rescheduling 2 pods happen to be on the same node and when this node itself is rescheduled all of our pods are gone for a while resulting in connection troubles (we have just 2 pods that are load balanced).

I think the best way to fix it is to not allow 2 pods to run on the same node and to use inter-pod anti-affinity for that.

Is this the correct solution to the problem? I tried to understand it but got a bit bogged down with `topologyKey` and the syntax. Can someone explain/give an example on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right Affinity is your friend here and is the correct solution.

Node Affinity : will help your app or microservice to stick to a particular kind of node (in a multinode architecture) like below my app `ngnix-ms` always sticks to the nodes which have a label `role=admin`.

The pod antiAffinity rule: sticks to the node labels (topologyKey) and makes sure that group (marked with topologyKey) of nodes.

If there is a node which already has a pod with the label `component=nginx`, K8s won't allow to spin up a pod.

Here is the explanation:

```
affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: role
              operator: In
              values:
              - app-1
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: component
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx-ms
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/1-hostname"
```

and

```
kubectl get node --show-labels
    
NAME                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   LABELS
xx-admin-1      Ready    master   19d   v1.13.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/1-hostname=xx-admin-1,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,role=admin
xx-admin-2      Ready    master   19d   v1.13.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/1-hostname=xx-admin-2,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,role=admin
xx-plat-1-1     Ready    <none>   19d   v1.13.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/2-hostname=xx-plat-1-1,role=admin
xx-plat-2-1     Ready    <none>   19d   v1.13.4   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/2-hostname=xx-plat-2-1,role=admin
```

Explanation of topologyKey:
Think of it as a label, now you can have two different topologies in the same cluster.

example: `kubernetes.io/1-hostname` and `kubernetes.io/2-hostname`

Now when you are doing podAntiAffinity you set `topologyKey:

`kubernetes.io/1-hostname`

Then your rule is valid in all the nodes with that topologyKey but your rule is not valid in `topologyKey: kubernetes.io/2-hostname` labelled nodes.

Hence, in my example pods are scheduled within nodes with the label `kubernetes.io/1-hostname` and has podAntiAffinity implied, but nodes with labels `kubernetes.io/2-hostname` doesn't have the podAntiAffinity rule!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it does answer the question, though I have actually decided to not go that way but use PodDisruptionBudget instead, you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create NodeAffinity and taints for this.

**For Node affinity**

```
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
          - matchExpressions:
            - key: role
              operator: In
              values:
              - app
```

**For taints use** 
`kubectl taint nodes <nodename> key=example-key:NoSchedule`

**Add this in your yaml file.**

```
  tolerations:
  - key: "example-key"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoSchedule"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have decided in the end to not use Pod Anti Affinity, but use a rather simpler mechanism in Kubernetes that is called Pod Disruption Budget. It generally says that at least X pods have to run at a given time.

```
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: myapp-disruption-budget
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
```

This will not allow a pod to be evicted before another pod is up and running. This fixes the problem with controlled downtime for node, but if node goes down uncontrollable (failures with hardware, etc.), then there is no guarantee, but hopefully this does not happen too often.

Comment: Hope is not a strategy
https://sre.google/sre-book/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way out, in case you don't to use pod affinity as described above ( or any such network policy to keep things simple), then at real time you can still handle this scenario if your Node gets down.

Make it cordon, so that it no longer appears to kubernetes for traffic scheduling and ultimately it will do that for other nodes which are working.

Please have a glance at attached file.

Finally you can uncordon that node, once it gets ready.[image: cordon and uncordon the node]

Comment: This still doesn't fix the problem if the node goes down for some unexpected reason. This works well for planned downtime.

Comment: Yes, I was interested in how to prevent this from happening rather on how to do this one time, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: For prevention network policy has to be used, likely you need to set pod affinity